# CSS: How to transform into a css class the stylesheet link from fonts.google.com to my file.css (from external to internal?

Tags: windows-10, fonts, html, css

I have this 2 option copy from fonts.google.com

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400&display=swap');
</style>
```

I want to keep this font, but also to copy into my file.css in order to make a class, such as this one?

```
.doneazab {font-family: sans-serif;color: #343434;}
```

So, how can I transform that google font style link into a class?

Answer (score -1):

You’ll want to set the `font-family`, like this:

```css
.doneazab {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #343434;
}
```

If you visit [the URL you’re loading from Google Fonts](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:wght@200;300;400&display=swap), you’ll see that it’s a CSS file with `@font-face` declarations. All those declarations define the `font-family` name as `Source Sans Pro`, which make it possible for you to reference that name elsewhere in your CSS.

This is also shown underneath the other code snippet for `link` or `@import` [on Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Source+Sans+Pro?query=source+s&sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Source+Sans+Pro), ex:

[image: Screenshot of the Google Fonts code snippet interface]

Comment: my problem was this part of the css, which isn't tell me nothing `wght@200;300;400&display=swap`